# Javascript persistent-sorting Object "class"

Tags: javascript, json

Attending to it's specification, JSON elements (and javascript objects) are unordered so, even in almost all cases, when you iterate over a javascript object, you get elements in the same order they was defined; you definitively cannot trust in that order because engine is allowed to alter it.

This is extremely rare. I have been able to observe it one time, but I don't find that code right now and I don't remember the exact version of JS engine (but it was node). If I manage to find it, I will add it to this post.

That being said, the point is that code relying in this behaviour can (and should) be considered buggy because, even it will work as expected in most engines, it may fail typically because of internal engine optimisations.

For example:

```
"use strict";
var x = {
    b: 23,
    a: 7
};

function someSorting(input) {
    var output = {};
    Object.keys(input).sort().map(
        function(k){
            output[k] = input[k];
        }
    );
    return output;
};

x = someSorting(x);
// Some smart engine could notice that input and output objects have the
// exact same properties and guess that, attending the unordered nature of
// javascript Object, there is no need to actually execute someSorting();

console.log(x);
// Usually will display: { a: 7, b: 23 }
// But perfectly we could got: { b: 23, a: 7 }
```

**I know** there is too many literature (even StackOverflow questions) about this (NON-) issue and "workarrounds" to achieve the expected behaviour by sorting keys in a separate array.

But doing so code goes too messy compared in simply trusting in key order.

I'm pretty sure that this can be achieved in a more elegant fashion by implementing a so-called "sObject" alternative having native Object as its prototype but overloading it's native iterator and setter so that:

- When any new property is added, it's key is appended to an Array index mantained under the hood.
- When an sObject *instance* is iterated, our customized iterator uses that index to retrieve elements in the right order.

**In summary:** Actual Object specification is right because, in most cases, properties order doesn't care. So I think that engine optimisations that could mess it are wonderfull.

But it would be also wonderful to have an alternative *sObject* with which we could do something like:

```
var x = new sObject({b: 23, a: 7});
```

...and trust that we could iterate it **in the same exact** order or, also / at least, do some sorting task over it and trust that this will not be altered.

**Of course!!** I'm initalyzing it with a native javascript Object so, in fact, theoretically we can't trust that it will be populated right (even I can't imagine why any engine *optimisation* should alter it before any operation).

I used that notation for brevity (and, I confess) because I expect that, in that case *should* work always (even I'm not really sure). However we even could sort it later (which, in most cases we will do that way) or use other kind of initialization like providing a JSON string or an array of objects (or arrays) with single key and value pairs.

My concern is: Such a thing exists yet? I wasn't able to find it. But sure I'm not the first guy thinking in that...

I can try to implement it (I'm thinking about that). I think it's possible and that I could achieve it. But it's not as simple so first I want to be sure that I'm not reinventing the wheel...

So any comments, suggestions, etc... will be welcome.

Comment: Do you realize that ES6 specifies that keys are enumerated in the order they are added to the object?  My understanding is that this was added to ES6 to document existing behaviors in the latest ES5 JS engines.  There is no simple way of changing the order though.

Comment: I might suggest that you make it easier to find the question in your question.  As it stands now, you expect people to do a LOT of reading before they can finally find what the question is.  Also [JSON is a text interchange format](http://json.org/) so that isn't the right term to use in your question.  Perhaps you just mean "Javascript objects" or "Javascript literals".

Comment: @jfriend00, I know that's certain for the new [Map spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), but is that the same for objects?

Comment: @Andy - Yes, it is specified for objects in ES6.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could do all this. You will need some machinery such as `Object.observer`, which is currently only available in Chrome. We can define this as the following:

```
function myObject(object) {

  // if the object already has keys, bring them in in whatever order.
  var keys = Object.keys(object);

  // Override Object.keys to return our list of keys.
  Object.defineProperty(object, 'keys', { get: function() { return keys; });

  // Watch the object for new or deleted properties.
  // Add new ones at the end, to preserve order.
  Object.observe(object, function(changes) {
    changes.forEach(function(change) {
      if (change.type === 'add') keys.push(change.name);
      if (change.type === 'delete') keys = keys.filter(function(key) {
        return key === change.name;
      });
    });
  });

  return object;
}
```

Note that `Object.observe` is asynchronous, so even after you add a property to the object, it won't be reflected in the custom `keys` property until after a tick of the clock, although in theory you could use `Object.deliverChangedRecords`.

The above approach uses a function which adds the new ordered key functionality to an existing object. Of course there are other ways to design this.

This "solution" obviously cannot control the behavior of `for...in` loops.